# Pinescript to Thinkscript request

Tags: pine-script, stock, trading, thinkscript

What is this calculating based off of? Volume, float? Idk, but would love some help trying to understand.

While I understand the basics of pinescript/thinkscript and have converted some other simple scripts from pinescript to thinkscript this one is beyond me.

Thanks

```
// © blackcat1402
//@version=4

study("[blackcat] L1 Banker Entry Indicator", overlay=false)

//functions
xrf(values, length) =>
    r_val = float(na)
    if length >= 1
        for i = 0 to length by 1
            if na(r_val) or not na(values[i])
                r_val  :=  values[i]
                r_val
    r_val
xsa(src,len,wei) =>
    sumf = 0.0
    ma = 0.0
    out = 0.0
    sumf  :=  nz(sumf[1]) - nz(src[len]) + src
    ma  :=  na(src[len]) ? na : sumf/len
    out  :=  na(out[1]) ? ma : (src*wei+out[1]*(len-wei))/len
    out


//model of banker model with customized input threshold
bankerthreshold = input(3, title="banker entry threshold", type=input.integer, minval = 1)
bankermodel = (3)*(xsa(((close - lowest(low,27))/(highest(high,27) - lowest(low,27)))*(100),5,1)) - (2)*(xsa(xsa(((close - lowest(low,27))/(highest(high,27) - lowest(low,27)))*(100),5,1),3,1))
pumpdumpsoon = iff(crossover(bankermodel,bankerthreshold),100,0)
longshortentry = iff((bankermodel <= 3),50,0)
bankermove = iff((bankermodel < 5),25,0)

//model banker pump or dump start soon
ppumpdumpsoon = plot(pumpdumpsoon,color=color.green, linewidth=3,style=plot.style_area, transp=30)
//model long short entry
plongshortentry = plot(longshortentry,color=color.orange, linewidth=3,style=plot.style_area, transp=30)
//model banker move
pbankermove = plot(bankermove,color=color.yellow, linewidth=3,style=plot.style_area, transp=70)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the function `xrf` is never used. Secondly, the function `xsa` is called with the combination of the variables [`close`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#var_close), [`low`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#var_low) and [`high`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#var_high). The combination is:

```
((close - lowest(low,27))/(highest(high,27) - lowest(low,27)))
```

which seems to scale the `close` price between `0` and `1`. Here is an example:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/

//@version=5
indicator("My Script")

src = ((close - ta.lowest(low,27))/(ta.highest(high,27) - ta.lowest(low,27)))

plot(src)
hline(0.5)
```

Which produces an image like this:
[image: Close Price Scaler]